# ILP - "Is variable equal to another variable"

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

In an ILP, given two variables x and y, is it possible to define a variable z where

z = (x==y)?

Meaning, if x equals y then z = 1.
Else, z = 0.

x and y are integer variables bounded between (1, M).

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `x <= y`, then you can use `z in {0,1}, x+Mz >= y, x+z <= y`.

If you don't know which of `x` and `y` is minimum, you can do it with more work, by adding a variable `minxy` which takes the value of the minimum. You need to introduce another new variable (which I call `a`) to do this.

Introduce a variable `a` that's 0 if x<=y, 1 if y<=x (it could be either 0 or 1 if x==y):

```
a in {0,1}, x-y <= Ma, y-x <= M(1-a)
```

Introduce a variable `minxy` that's the minimum of `x` and `y`:

```
minxy <= x
minxy <= y
minxy >= x - Ma
minxy >= y - M(1-a)
```

Then you can define your `z`:

```
minxy + Mz >= x + y - minxy
minxy + z <= x + y - minxy
```

(Noting that `max(x,y)` is `x + y - minxy`).

Comment: This is a reasonable approach. If M is large enough, an SOS1 formulation might work better. Depending on the rest of the model, it might be a better fit for constraint programming than ILP.